# Weird initialization in C

Tags: c

I have this piece of code and i don't know how it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numero = ({const int i = 10; i+10;});

    printf("%d\n", numero); // Prints 20

    return 0;
}
```

Why if i delete the second part (i+10;), the compiler gets an error?
Why are the brackets necessary?

Thank you ^^!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a [GCC statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). It executes the statements in it, and returns the value evaluated in the last statement. Thus `numero` is initialized to `20`. If you delete the second part, there is no expression as the last statement, so it can't get a value from the statement expression.

The braces are necessary to disambiguate it from ordinary C parenthesized expressions.